# Disable empty_value FormType Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I want to disable the empty_value by default in my form type.
how to do this ?

```html
->add('subject', 'choice', array(
          'label'  => 'Subject',
          'choices' => array(
           '1'  => 'contact.Appreciation',
           '2'  => 'contact.Feedback',
           '3'  => 'contact.Dissatisfactions',
           '4'  => 'contact.My account',
           '5'  => 'contact.Recruitment',
           '6'  => 'contact.Other',
          ),
          'attr'  => array(
           'class'  => 'form-control'
          ),
            'required'        => false,
            'empty_value'   => 'contact.Subject',
         ))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable specific item in form choice type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344639/how-to-disable-specific-item-in-form-choice-type)

Answer (score 0):

Change required to true.

'required' => true

See [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#required)

Comment: You don't understand what i want to do :
I want to add "disabled" to the first option by default :

http://snapplr.com/snap/fbg7

Comment: HTML property disabled for the <option> tag?

Comment: yes, i found a solution but, on Jquery, i want to change it in my formType.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution for this, but you can use an **event listener** on the **PRE_BIND** event.

See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346520/606104